# How to calculate needed disk space for InnoDB databases?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have several databases in MySQL with InnoDB engine. All together they have around 30 GB size on filesystem. A couple of days ago, I removed a lot of data from those databases (~10-15 GB) but the used space on filesystem is the same and also reading data_length and index_length from information_schema.TABLES give almost the old size.

I dumped a 3,3 GB database and imported it on my workstation where it takes only 1,1 GB (yes, it is a 1:1 copy). So, how can I calculate the size a InnoDB database needs if I would reimport it in a new system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimize your tables after deleting large amouts of data.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: From manual: `For InnoDB tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE, which rebuilds the table to update index statistics and free unused space in the clustered index. `

Comment: Sorry Mchl, I should have been more clear.  It "works" in that sense; but it doesn't free most the space - see the link in my answer.  There are a few feature request/bug reports on it, but it's been a known problem for years and they still show no sign of fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Mchl and El Yobo. I felt still lost even with your answers, so I made an experiment: I took my fresh imported table and wrote down DATA_LENGTH and INDEX_LENGTH, then I deleted half of the data from the table and wrote down the sizes again. Then I run OPTIMIZE TABLE and at the end I dropped the table and reimported it. Short result: OPTIMIZE TABLE is enough.

       | ROWS | DATA_LENGTH | INDEX_LENGTH
Step 1 | 885449 | 390971392 | 577404928
Step 2 | 444449 | 377864192 | 563052544
Step 3 | 444449 | 195772416 | 291864576
Step 4 | 444449 | 195772416 | 291864576

Comment: The effectiveness of this method can also be dependent on your table structure, but don't ask me for details. Anyway good job on doing an experiment!

Answer (score 3):

InnoDB doesn't free disk space; it's a PITA.  Basically, you can free it by dropping the database and restoring it from a backup (as you've noticed by chance) - see [here for examples](http://mysqlhacker.com/kabir/innodb/reclaiming-your-innodb-tablespace.html).

So, you can't calculate how big a database will be after you restore a backup.  *But* it will never be bigger than the un-backed up one (because the unbacked up version still has space from any deleted data and the restored backup will *not* have that space).

This can be worked around to some extent using the file per table option; more details in the first link from this post.